# TinyMCE Angular component keeps refreshing page on save

Tags: angular, tinymce

I'm trying to setup the Angular TinyMCE component in a form and use the save plugin so the user can use ctrl/cmd + S and the save button to save and submit the form.

But the problem is the page always gets refreshed on save. I've tried adding `event.preventDefault()` but that doesn't keep it from refreshing either.

Here's a small codebox https://codesandbox.io/embed/tinymceangular-5thjg

```
<form #editorForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate id="editorForm" submit="return false;">
  <button type="submit" mat-raised-button color="primary" name="submitbtn">Save Changes</button>
  <editor
    [(ngModel)]="editor" name="editor"
    (onSaveContent)="$event.event.preventDefault();false;"
    [init]="{
    plugins: 'media table contextmenu  save',
    toolbar: 'save',
    branding: false
  }"></editor>
</form>
```

---

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-table-editor',
  templateUrl: './table-editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table-editor.component.scss']
})
export class TableEditorComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() tableId: number;
  editor: string;
  @ViewChild('editorForm') editorForm: NgForm;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
              private tableService: DataTableService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.tableService.getActiveTableDocumentation(this.tableId)
      .subscribe((documentation: DocumentationContent) => {
        this.editor = documentation.content;
      });
    this.listenForSaveEvent();
  }
  listenForSaveEvent() {
    this.editorForm.statusChanges.subscribe(change => console.log(change));
    this.editorForm.valueChanges.subscribe(change => console.log(change));
  }

  saveEvent(evt: Event) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    console.log('saving');
  }
  onSubmit(): boolean {
    console.log(this.editorForm);
    return false;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the TinyMCE Save plugin is using a standard form submission which would result in the page being reloaded.

If you want to rely on your Angular application's save code you could create a custom shortcut for that keystroke that triggers your JavaScript code for form submission.